# Changing values in Set<?>

Tags: java, collections

I have a set containing Item objects: `Set<Item>`
The class Item has a method `getName()` that returns a string.
I want to convert `Set<Item>` to `Set<String>` using the method 
`Item#getName()`

Any better way, rather than using forEach ?

Comment: `Set<String> result = itemSet.stream().map(item -> item.getName()).collect(Collectors.toSet())` should transform it

Comment: Problem solved. Thanks :)

Comment: A method reference (`.map(Item::getName)`) would probably be better than the lambda (`.map(item -> item.getName())`), but either way works.

Comment: Dear down-voter, please leave a criticism along with your vote. This may be a seemingly simple question, but (a) simple questions are certainly allowed on Stack Overflow, and (b) it leads to [an interesting Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52466471/642706) about Java Streams.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
itemSet.stream().map(Item::getName).collect(Collectors.toSet())
```

Explaining this [method-chain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining) using Java Stream:

- The `.stream` pulls each item from your set, one after another. See this article published by Oracle, [*Processing Data with Java SE 8 Streams, Part 1*](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/ma14-java-se-8-streams-2177646.html).
- The `.map` calls the specified method (`getName`) on each object streaming from your set. The output of this is each item’s name property, apparently a `String` object in your scheme.
- The `.collect` captures each of those name outputs, and puts them into a fresh `Set` object. This new `Set` is returned when this code completes.

[image]

Comment: @basil-bourque Thanks for fleshing out my answer - very neat explanation of the steps!

Comment: Well, let's take it up one more notch, with a nifty diagram. Inspired by that linked article.

Comment: I really like this answer and the diagram. However, I believe that the concepts are wrong. It's not the `.stream()` method the one which pulls the items from the set, but the terminal operation of the stream instead (in this case `collect`). All the pipeline is lazy, meaning that the parameters of the intermediate operations are called only if needed, when needed. Conceptually, when `collect` triggers the start of the pipeline, elements are pulled from the source, then intermediate operations are applied in order (when it corresponds) and finally, the terminal operation is applied.